# Disabling/customizing touch-related input UI in Chrome Kiosk-mode

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, accessibility, kiosk

I am currently working on a kiosk-ish project on Windows platform, where the user should fill in their contact info. I’ve used the input element with the custom on-screen keyboard, so I don’t need OS-level stuff, but the only problem left is native Chrome UI for interaction with inputs like “tear” cursor and context menu for text-editing actions (copy, paste, etc). I have two questions:

- can I customize the color of this “tear” cursor?
- can I hide this context menu?

[image]

I’ve already made `event.preventDefault()` with  “contextmenu” event аnd used these flags with Chrome shortcut:
`--chrome --fullscreen --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --no-context-menu --kiosk` …

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the text un selectable so that the user can not click on it for a word selection and so the tear cursor will also not appear with the context menu

Till it is editable the tear cursor ui and  functionality is from the native side of the phone which can't be changed.

For hiding the context menu make the input text selection to disable which may be an option but we can't disable selection in an input.  Try with custom input

Comment: The problem is that I need that cursor and user selection for better UX, and it’s not mobile device - it’s large touch screen